# TypeError: ProjectNotifications is not iterable at fetchNotifications

Tags: javascript, reactjs, push-notification

I'm getting error while merging two function in notification ,there is an error in "            const mergedNotifications = [...ProjectNotifications, ...RoleNotifications];" and while calling that function again fetchNotifications();

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hsg8X.png)  useEffect(() => {
    // Define an async function inside useEffect
    async function fetchNotifications() {
        try {
            
            // Merge project and role notifications
            const mergedNotifications = [...ProjectNotifications, ...RoleNotifications];

            // Sort the merged notifications based on their fetch time
            mergedNotifications.sort((a, b) => new Date(b.fetchTime) - new Date(a.fetchTime));

            // Update the state with the sorted notifications
            setNotifications(mergedNotifications);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error("Error fetching notifications:", error);
        }
    };
    // Call the async function immediately
    fetchNotifications();
}, []);
```